# Problem with loading collection from datafile

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sql-update, realm

I'm stuck with issue on loading my observable collection from realm database. I created a function where i create this list and every time a list is a null , it creates a new one , my problem is how to set to read does once created list from data base using realm ? For any help in putting me on good track with this i would be really appreciated : ) Thank you in advance for your time :)

ListViewModel code :

```
public PeopleListViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        realmDb = Realm.GetInstance();
        LoadDb();
    }
    private void LoadDb()
    {
        var _realmDb = Realm.GetInstance();
        Debug.WriteLine("Reading wastes collection");
        PeopleCOllection = _realmDb.All<Person>() as ObservableCollection<Person>;
        if (PersonCollection == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Collection Empty");
            CreatePeopleList();
        }
        SaveDb();
    }

    private void SaveDb()
    {
        var _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        _realm.Write(() =>
        {
            foreach (var person in PeopleCollection)
            {
                _realm.Add(person);
                Debug.WriteLine("Person saved into collection!");
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't do this cast:

```
PeopleCOllection = _realmDb.All<Person>() as ObservableCollection<Person>;
```

To create a observable collection from your db results you should do something like this:

```
PeopleCOllection = new ObservableCollection<Person>(_realmDb.All<Person>().ToList());
```

Comment: Okey, when i did that , my app creates about 1000 of records but i had only 14 objects created for that purpose, and every single is now added into a realm db . How can i avoid that ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. What is your main purpose? It seems like you are reading the records and immediately save them again in the same method `LoadDb`.

Comment: Main purpose is to load my objects which were created at first lunch of app (14 items) and to be that way. My issue was that they were not loading from db , now it loaded them like 1000 times. it duplicate them

Comment: Ok I think I got it. First try completely reinstalling your app, since there may be already saved records from your previous debugging. Then, I would put the `SaveDb` method inside your `if` statement and change the condition to `if (PeopleCOllection.Count == 0)` in order to call the action just when there is no records.

Comment: ok :) , it works :) I just reinstall app from simulator and working as expected ! :) Thank you :)